# Missing argument 1 y 2 for WP_Widget

Tags: wordpress, widget

I have a problem and rather than try to see where this can not find it now. Wordpress returns me the following Warning:

```
Missing argument 1 for WP_Widget :: __ construct ()
Missing argument 2 for WP_Widget::__construct()
```

My code is:

```
class WP_Mrw_Widget extends WP_Widget {  

function Mrw_Widget(){

        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'MiRegata', 'description' => 'Plugin para mostrar las regatas ya finalizadas' );


        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'mrw_widget' );

        $this->WP_Widget( 'mrw_widget', 'Mi Regata Widget', $widget_ops, $control_ops );
    }
 function widget($args, $instance){

 }

function update($new_instance, $old_instance){

}

function form($instance){

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of the problem is

```
function Mrw_Widget(){
    parent::__construct('Mrw_Widget',"MiRegata",array("description"=>"Widet que nos muestra las ultimas regatas disputadas"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When extending `WP_Widget`, your subclass must register your widget with WordPress by calling the parent constructor. For example:

```
/**
 * Register widget with WordPress.
 */
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
        'foo_widget', // Base ID
        __( 'Widget Title', 'text_domain' ), // Name
        array( 'description' => __( 'A Foo Widget', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
    );
}
```

That's most probably why you're seeing the missing argument notice.

Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Example

Comment: The problem persists my new code is:                                                       function __construct() {
  parent::__construct(
   'mrw_widget', // Base ID
   __( 'Widget Title', 'MiRegata' ), // Name
   array( 'description' => __( 'A Mrw_Widget', 'Plugin para mostrar las regatas ya finalizadas' ), ) // Args
  );
 }

Comment: You should provide the full code you're using in your question.

Comment: Thanks, although the formatting isn't right. Try formatting the code as a code block.